# Django model variable pointing at a function not working

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, function, model-view-controller

I have the following:

```
class College(models.Model):
    url_name = create_url_name()
    def create_url_name(self):
        return self.name.lower().replace("the", "").strip().replace(" ", "_")
```

But when I run it I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'create_url_name' is not defined
```

All I'm doing is calling a function I made, how come it doesn't work?

Comment: You're not calling the function you've made because the one you made belongs to an instance of the class

Comment: What did you expect? If you moved the definition of `create_url_name` before the `url_name` field it would not have given that error (but it would fail in a different manner).

Answer (score 5):

If you want a slug for your url you can use "SlugField" like that:

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

class College(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
    url_name = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url_name = slugify(self.name)
        super(College, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can also use the same method with your code:

```
class College(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
    url_name = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url_name = self.name.lower().replace("the", "").strip().replace(" ", "_")
        super(College, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a function and not the method replace `create_url_name()` for `self.create_url_name()`:

```
    class College(models.Model):
        url_name = self.create_url_name()

        def create_url_name(self):
            return self.name.lower().replace("the", "").strip().replace(" ", "_")
```

A property would be better:

```
    class College(models.Model):

        @property
        def url_name(self):
            return self.name.lower().replace("the", "").strip().replace(" ", "_")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in python you have to declare the function before you call it, so you'd have to move url_name = create_url_name() to after the declaration.

But even if you do this, you'll get an error because the function is intended to be called on an object, but it's being called on an uninstantiated class.

This would work:

```
class College(models.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        models.Model.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.url_name = self.create_url_name()

    def create_url_name(self):
        return self.name.lower().replace("the", "").strip().replace(" ", "_")
```